# PhpExcel: вывод таблицы на сайт

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Уважаемые знатоки, очень нужен совет.

Я использую библиотеку PhpExcel для генерации таблицы. Таблица генерируется исправно, пользователь ее скачивает и открывает в экселе.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы данная таблица отображалась прямо на сайте?

Первый пример, который пришел в голову, это почта gmail. Если на почту приходят эксель-файлы, то я могу не скачивать, а посмотреть таблицу прямо там. Не исключаю, что я вообще пошел неверным путем. На всякий случай поясню, что я делаю в целом. Мой сайт отображает прайс-листы товаров (не интернет-магазин, а просто прайсы). Прайс генерируется, когда посетитель выбирает какие-либо критерии своего поиска. И мне кажется неудобным заставлять человека каждый раз скачивать данный прайс. Буду рад любым советам. Спасибо всем, кто поможет.

Answer (score 1):

А что мешают юзать

```
<table>
...
</table>
```

К тому же есть куча готовых библиотек для отображения таблиц, фильтр, пагинация и прочие примочки.
Мне нравится вот этот плагин [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).